# Python - loop over dict. search for elements in dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
IDAX = [3, 8, 10, 12]
AXID = [3, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12]
BT = [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]

BT = [str(x) for x in BT]

AX_BR = dict(zip(AXID, BT))
```

Result:

```
{3: '1', 5: '1', 6: '1', 8: '1', 10: '0', 12: '0'}
```

Now i want for every element in IDAX the correct BT-Value.

How can i search for elements in a dictonary?

Thanks!

Comment: `{key: int(AX_BR[key]) for key in IDAX}`

Answer (score 2):

You are using the list var name as the same for iteration var name.

```
>>> IDAX = [3, 8, 10, 12]
>>> AXID = [3, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12]
>>> BT = [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
>>> BT = [str(x) for x in BT]
>>> AX_BR = dict(zip(AXID, BT))
>>> print AX_BR
{3: '1', 5: '1', 6: '1', 8: '1', 10: '0', 12: '0'}
>>> {i: AX_BR[i] for i in IDAX}
{3: '1', 8: '1', 10: '0', 12: '0'}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to loop over a dict; what you want is very basic dict usage:

```
>>> BT[8]
'1'
```

Or if you mean you want a list of pairs (IDAX, BT):

```
[(idax, BT[idax]) for idax in IDAX]
```

Comment: thanks. my aim is a list of pairs(IDAX, BT) but this error Error is coming:list indices must be integers, not list

Comment: You apparently did something different from my example: you're not supposed to index BT by the whole IDAX list but only by elements of it. In my list comprehension, this is achieved by using the loop variable as the index, which is one of the IDAX element at any given time. If this all doesn't make a lot of sense to you, please post a complete minimal example that exhibits the problem.

Answer (score -1):

i think ive solved the problem with a loop.

```
j = []
for i in range(len(IDAX)):
    j += AX_BR[(IDAX[i])]
print(j)
```

maybe not the best solution but it works.